# SQL to get top 3 from a table with at least one from opposite gender

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, h2

I have a database table like this

Users

```
id  Capacity Gender
----------------------
1     10     M
---------------------
2     9      M
---------------------
3     4      F
---------------------
4     8      M
---------------------
5     7      F
---------------------
```

And I want to retrieve the top 3 records ordered by capacity and with at least one from opposite gender using SQL, like below

```
id  Capacity Gender
----------------------
1     10     M
---------------------
2     9      M
---------------------
5     7      F
---------------------
```

I cant user 'partition by' since i'm not using oracle, I want one that works for H2 database, or database agnostic if possible.

Thanks in advance

Sam

Comment: I removed tag sql since you table is html format. Is it really sql or html?

Comment: Sorry, i edited it now, i'm looking for sql solution.

Comment: It seems to me the simplest thing to do would be to select the top 2 where gender = M and the top 2 where gender = F, and then pick the top 3 of those.

Comment: Thanks I put back tag sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite long since the requirement is also strict.
It is making use of self join and group by.
Get the top 2 per gender to ensure that both gender group is represented. Then get top 3.

```
SELECT id, capacity, gender
from (
SELECT t.id, t.gender, t.capacity,
       COUNT(*) AS rn
FROM t
   JOIN t AS t2
    ON  t2.gender = t.gender
   AND ( t2.capacity > t.capacity
          OR  t2.capacity = t.capacity
        AND t2.id <= t.id )
GROUP BY t.id, t.gender, t.capacity
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
ORDER BY t.capacity desc, rn ) tab
ORDER BY capacity desc 
LIMIT 3;

Result:
id  capacity    gender
1      10   M
2       9           M
5       7            F
```

Comment: This works in mySql, oracle and sqllite. For sqlserver you can put TOP 3 and remove Limit 3.

Comment: Btw, I have no experience in H2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, it works for this dataset on H2. Let me tweak it for my case and test it more.

Comment: Pls upvote and accept my answer if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little bit hacky but works for your issue I believe. Please try:

```
CREATE TABLE temp as
Select top 2 id, Gender, max(capacity) as maxcap
from table
where Gender ='F'
group by id, Gender 

CREATE TABLE temp2 as
Select top 2 id, Gender, max(capacity) as maxcap
from table
where Gender ='M'
group by id, Gender 

select top 3 id, gender, maxcap
from
(
   Select id, Gender, maxcap
   from temp
   union
   Select Gender, maxcap
   from temp2
) t
order by t.maxcap desc
```

Comment: I think you need to order temp and temp2 too. The max() and group there don't add anything so you're always getting the first two records. Would be neater if you could do this as CTEs though since H2 doesn't support per-connection temporary tables by the look of it.

Comment: Hi Eray, Thanks for the idea. I want to do it in single sql statement without using temp tables. Sam

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CTE answer, based on David Conrad's approach from the comments:

```
with f(id, gender, capacity) as (select top 2 id, gender, capacity from capacity
                                        where gender = 'F' order by capacity desc),
     m(id, gender, capacity) as (select top 2 id, gender, capacity from capacity
                                        where gender = 'M' order by capacity desc),
     combined(id, gender, capacity) as (select * from f union select * from m)
select top 3 * from combined order by capacity desc;
```

(assuming the table is called "capacity" too). Without a RANK() function I can't see how to do any better, and I'm nervous about performance of the [subquery count rank function suggested here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/h2-database/8GPeAUyIvac/K74a9fqtQV8J) on large tables, and you'll have to be careful about ties if you go down that route too. Tested on H2 and SQL Server.